# Why does the URL for this Stack Exchange use "scicomp," but the title says "Computational Science"?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps it's a trivial question, but why does the URL for this Stack Exchange use "scicomp," but the title of the Stack Exchange is "Computational Science"? I ask because the URL and the title seem inconsistent with respect to word order; I would've expected "Scientific Computing" as the title of the Stack Exchange based on the URL. I'm guessing part of the reason "scicomp" was used was to avoid using "compsci," which might confuse people looking to ask questions about computer science.

Comment: in the proposal phase on area51 people preferred the name "computational science" to "scientific computing". Check the related thread on area51 for the history of the arguments.

Comment: Check [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815?phase=definition) and [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/what-are-the-options-for-naming-the-computational-science-proposal).

Comment: I see. I find I have to fight the urge to call the site "Scientific Computing" after repeatedly referring to it using the term "SciComp". Occasionally, I see mods from other sites referring to it using language like "Scientific Computing"; I suppose I'll have to explain the distinction to them.

Comment: We refer to [cstheory.se] as cstheory and others also refer to it mostly as cstheory while the official title shown on top is different. So if the community chooses a name like "scicomp" and uses it consistently when referring to the site then others would follow the suit. It might still be possible to change the name (I am not sure but I think this might have happened on apple.se) but I am not sure it really worth the trouble, I think there need to be a quite strong support from the community of this site for SE to even consider it.

Answer (score 7):

You've pretty much got it in your question; `compsci` is already a common shorthand for Computer Science in a number of spheres. (For example, where I grew up -- just north of Dallas.) To avoid confusion between that subject and this, we opted for `scicomp` when doing the URL naming.

Comment: I think this is missing the purpose of the question, which I believe is "Why not title this group 'Scientific Computing?'"

Comment: I guess the answer to that is: that's not what computational science is, is it? Insofar as I can gather, using computers in science isn't really the same as scientifically using computers.

Comment: I think Computational Science approxi. = Scientific Computing right?

Comment: I think Computational Science encompasses scientific computing, but not necessarily the reverse. Scientific Computing—as we tend to think of it today—focuses more on how to run things on big machines; computational science has the broader focus of how to use numerical methods to solve problems.