# Why we use the name Computational Science?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Why we use the name Computational Science? I wonder why this name rather than Applied Mathematics.

Comment: Closely related: [Why does the URL for this Stack Exchange use "scicomp" but the title says "Computational Science"?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-does-the-url-for-this-stack-exchange-use-scicomp-but-the-title-says-comp)

Answer (score 5):

"Applied Math" is probably too wide, as we are focusing on **computational solutions** of various applied math problems. Moreover, the term "computational science [and engineering]" is a common term used for various academic and non-academic programs, institutions, etc.

A little bit more insight into the naming of this Stack Exchange community can be found [on the corresponding Area 51 page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/170893).